# SPTimerService (SPTimerV4) stopping and restarting every hour

Tags: error

My Service keeps stopping and then restarting ever hour on the hour. I have watched the service and form windows services and it does not stop at all but central admin keeps reporting that there is a problem ?
Running SharePoint 2010 on server 08 R2.

Comment: How is the memory level on the server? And the CPU? And the drives? Looks like something start hourly, taking up to much of the resources and forcing your SPTimerV4 to restart

Comment: Running virtual server with 16 gb of ram in use 4 gb with 2 processors. Wsus updates are only installed once a week.

Comment: In order to see it restart in windows services you'd have to refresh the services view while it's in the middle of restarting.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, this is performance issues. But if you've checked the ULS log in SharePoint, the Event Viewer on your server, disk usage and speed, memory load, processor workload and network load - and there are no sign of any performance issues - then you might want to try to move this service to another app server and see if your problems are the same on your second app server.

Also, check that your account running the service have [Log on as service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794944%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) permission.